# How to initialize this NodeList class in C

Tags: c, linked-list, initialization, singly-linked-list

I'm pretty newbie in C language and I have this little code in which I want to do some test in the main code.

```
struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};
```

I want to create some examples (For example: 4 -> 9 -> 1) in the main code, but I don't really know how to initialize them. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
struct ListNode* addnode(struct ListNode *head,int val)
{
    struct ListNode* newnode = malloc(sizeof(*this));
    newnode->val = val;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (!head) head = newnode;
    else {
        struct ListNode *this = head;
        while(this->next)
            this = this->next;
        this->next = newnode;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct ListNode *head = NULL;

    head = addnode(head,4);
    addnode(head,9);
    addnode(head,1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As we iterate through the lined-list (in the while loop) we only keep changing the pointer (with `this = this->next;`, then after the loop is the only time we change a value, which is to set the `next` value of the last entry in the list to point to the node just added (with `this->next = newnode;`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The only thing I don't understand is why does it work with your code : 
    head = addnode(head,4);
    addnode(head,9);
    addnode(head,1);
 
 and not with this one : 
    addnode(head,4);
    addnode(head,9);
    addnode(head,1);
 
 wouldn't it be the same considering you are using the same memory adress of head ? Sorry for bothering you, thank you in advance

Comment: Because `head` is undefined before the first call to `addnode`, and since it is a local variable in `addnode` there is no way for that value to get back to `main` except through the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Using this structure you need in main at first to declare a pointer to the head node of the list and initialize it as a null pointer. For example

```
struct ListNode *head = NULL;
```

Then you need to write a function that will store values in the list by dynamically allocating nodes that will be added to the list. Or you could create dynamically nodes in a loop if you a going to do all the functionality in main.

Pay attention to that if you have a singly-linked list then it is more efficient to add new nodes to the beginning of the list. Or if you want to add new nodes to the tail of the list then you should declare a two-sided singly-linked list like for example

```
struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct List
{
    struct ListNode *head;
    struct ListNode *tail;
};
```

In this case declaration of the list in main can look like

```
struct List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
```